# git clone branch into master

Tags: git, github

I've worked for about a year on a "dev" branch, now I need to push all the changes to "master", or more like clone dev into master as the structure of the project changed quite a bit and I don't want to resolve conflicts on each and every file.

I mostly use gui like GitHub desktop/source tree/gitkraken, and have no experience with the bash.

How can I achieve this? thanks

Comment: Very naive solution would be checkout master at local and replace its contents with dev branch. Post that push your your changes into master.

Comment: @RomainValeri I want to keep both master and dev, ideally keep working on dev and merge my changes into master once in a while, but I need to replace the actual too old content of master first

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about the history of master branch you can reset it to develop and force push.

```
git checkout master
git reset develop --hard
git push --force
```

If you want to keep the history, than it is a bit more complicated than that.

Comment: I don't expecially care about the history but I have no experience with the bash version … :/